# Hawaiian pronouncer

Tags: python, python-3.x

so I am supposed to make a program that takes in a inputted Hawaiian word and outputs the pronunciation.

Rules:

- p,k,h,l,m,n are pronounced the same as they are in English.
- W as the start of the word or after the letter a, u, or o is pronounced as a w. but if it is after the letter i or e it is pronounced as a v.
- for vowels: a is pronounced as "ah", e as "eh", i as "ee" , o as "oh" , u as "oo"
- for groups vowels: ai is pronounced "eye", ae is "eye" , ao is "ow" , au is "ow" , ei is "ay" , eu is "eh-oo" , iu is "ew" , oi is "oyo" , ou is "ow" and ui is "ooey"

What I've got going:
So I have been able to have it recognize the vowels and the grouped vowels and place it into a converted word, but it completely skips over the letters that are not vowels or grouped vowels. I am having difficulty finding my mistake. For example, if I inputted "aloha" it should output "ah-loh-hah" , or if I inputted "mahalo" it should output "mah-hah-loh" , but it completely skips a few characters. With my code aloha just prints out "ah-ah" which is just wrong.

Below is my code:

```
consonants = ('p','k','h','l','m','n')
def check(valid, word):
    for x in word:
        x = x.lower()
        if valid.count(x) == 0:
            print(x, "is not a valid hawaiian word")
            return False
    return True
def convert(word):
   convert = ""
   x = 0
   while x < len(word)-1:
        word = word.lower()    
        if word[x] == "a":
            after_x = word[x+1]
            if after_x == "i" or after_x == "e":
                convert = convert + "eye-"
                x = x+1
            elif after_x == 'o' or after_x == "u":
                convert = convert + "ow-"
                x=x+1
            else:
                convert = convert + "ah-" 
        elif word[x] == "e":
            after_x = word[x+1]
            if after_x == "i":
                convert = convert + "ay-"
                x = x+1
            elif after_x == 'u':
                convert = convert + "eh-oo-"
                x= x+1
            elif after_x == 'w': #
                convert = convert + "v"
                x=x+1
            else:
                convert = convert + "eh-"
        elif word[x] == "i":
            after_x = word[x+1]
            if after_x == "u":
                convert = convert + "ew-"
                x = x+1
            else:
                convert = convert + "ee-"        
        elif word[x] == "o":
            after_x = word[x+1]
            if after_x == "i":
                convert = convert + "oy-"
                x = x+1
            elif after_x == "u":
                convert = convert + "ow-"
                x = x+1
            elif after_x == 'w': #
                convert = convert + "v"
                x = x+1
            else:
                convert = convert + "oh-"   
        elif word[x] == "u":
            after_x = word[x+1]
            if after_x == "i":
                convert = convert + "ooey-"
                x = x+1
            else:
                convert = convert + "oo-"
        elif word[x] == consonants:
            convert = convert + consonants        
        elif word[x] == " " and convert[len(convert)-1] == "-":
            convert = convert[0:len(convert)-1] + " "
        elif word[x] == "\'" and convert[len(convert)-1] == "-":
            convert = convert[0:len(convert)-1] + "'"
        else:
            convert = convert + word[x]
        x = x +1 
        if x < len(word):
            m = word[len(word)-1]
            m = m.lower()
            if m == "a" or m == "e" or m == "o":
                convert = convert + m + "h"
            elif m == "i":
                convert = convert + "ee"
            elif m == "u":
                convert = convert + "oo"
            else:
                convert = convert + m
        if convert[len(convert)-1] == '-':
            convert = convert[0:len(convert)-1]
        convert = convert.upper()
        return convert
def main():
    valid = ['p','k','h','l','m','n','w','a','e','i','o','u',' ', '\'']
    while True:
        word = input("Enter a Hawaiian Word to Pronounce")
        word = word.strip()
        if(check(valid,word)):
            converted_word = convert(word)
            converted_word = converted_word.upper()
            print(word + " is pronounced" , converted_word)          
        repeat = input("Would you like to enter another word Y/YES/N/NO")
        repeat = repeat.upper()
        if repeat == 'N' or repeat == 'NO':
            break
        else:
            main()        
main()
```

Thank you.

Comment: There are some indentation errors in your code that will need to be fixed before it can be run.

Answer (score 2):

I think in your case it's better to use dictionaries:

```
VOWELS = {
    'a': 'ah',
    'e': 'eh',
    'i': 'ee',
    'o': 'oh',
    'u': 'oo'
}

VOWEL_PAIRS = {
    'ai': 'eye',
    'ae': 'eye',
    'ao': 'ow',
    'au': 'ow',
    'ei': 'ay',
    'eu': 'eh-oo',
    'iu': 'ew',
    'oi': 'oyo',
    'ou': 'ow',
    'ui': 'ooey',
    'iw': 'v',
    'ew': 'v'
}
```

Here is a function which converts a given word into a transcription:

```
def pronounce(word):
    chars = word.lower()

    i = 0
    result = []

    while i < len(chars):
        char = chars[i]

        if i < len(chars) - 1:
            pair = char + chars[i + 1]
            tr = VOWEL_PAIRS.get(pair)

            if tr is None:
                tr = VOWELS.get(char)
            else:
                i = i + 1
        else:
            tr = VOWELS.get(char)

        if tr is not None and i < len(chars) - 1:
            tr = tr + '-'

        result.append(tr or char)
        i = i + 1

    return ''.join(result)
```

And the results look as follows:

```
>>> pronounce('aloha')
'ah-loh-hah'
>>> pronounce('mahalo')
'mah-hah-loh'
```

Comment: Good try, but your VOWEL_PAIRS dictionary will never be consulted.  When you have a vowel pair, the VOWELS dict will return a non-`None` value for `tr`, so you will never enter the if condition to check for a VOWEL_PAIRS possibility.