# Hawaiian Pronunciation

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hitting a snag with an assignment and thought I'd ask for help. The goal is to be able to pronounce Hawaiian words. Been successful with everything else from another post linked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55291856/hawaiian-pronouncer) but only issue is that if there is a space in the original word, it is intentional. So when I try the word 'E komo mai' the return value is eh- kohmoh meye. I put all the code I have used so far with the function calls to test. Any help would be appreciated.

```
# Variables
vowels = {
    'a': 'ah',
    'e': 'eh',
    'i': 'ee',
    'o': 'oh',
    'u': 'oo'
}

vowelPairs = {
    'ai': 'eye',
    'ae': 'eye',
    'ao': 'ow',
    'au': 'ow',
    'ei': 'ay',
    'eu': 'eh-oo',
    'iu': 'ew',
    'oi': 'oyo',
    'ou': 'ow',
    'ui': 'ooey',
    'iw': 'v',
    'ew': 'v'
}
# Not used but is part of it so is in dictionary for reference
constants = {
    'p': 'p',
    'k': 'k',
    'h': 'h',
    'l': 'l',
    'm': 'm',
    'n': 'n'
}

# Checks for valid characters in the input
def check(word):
    valid = ['p', 'k', 'h', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'w',
             'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', ' ', '\'']
    for c in word:
        c = c.lower()
        if valid.count(c) == 0:
            print(c, ' is not a valid character.')
            return False
    return True

# This function does the transition and pronunciation
def pronounce(word):
    chars = word.lower()
    print(len(chars))
    i = 0
    result = []

    while i < len(chars):
        char = chars[i]
        # print(char)
        if i < len(chars) - 1:
            print(char + chars[i + 1])
            pair = char + chars[i + 1]
            tr = vowelPairs.get(pair)

            if tr is None:
                tr = vowels.get(char)

            else:
                i = i + 1

        else:
            tr = vowels.get(char)
        if tr is not None and i < len(chars) - 1:
            tr = tr + '-'

        result.append(tr or char)
        i = i + 1

        wordResult = ''.join(result)

    print(wordResult)
    return wordResult


check('E komo mai')
pronounce('E komo mai')
```

Comment: What is the issue? The `-` character after `eh`? If so, you may check the condition: `if tr is not None and i < len(chars) - 1:` which adds it.

Comment: when I run your program I get : `'eh- koh-moh- meye'` . What is the issue ?

Comment: Think of Stack Overflow as a huge FAQ. A question title should be focused on a specific technical problem you encountered, not what kind of program you were writing when you encountered it.

Comment: Please specify what the output should be.

Comment: If I understand it right you need to create in first step a dictionary of words which consists of letter groups with spaces between them as key and their pronunciation as value which you then use to check if the input word is listed in this dictionary and if it is output the right pronunciation.

Comment: sorry about the delay everyone. The output should be ```'Eh koh-moh meye'```. but @GusSL, i'll mess with that and see if I can't fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I first split the word where-ever there was a space. This allows you to handle them seperately. I then added a few more if-statements and logic to the process.

Here is what I came up with:

```py
# Variables
vowels = {
    'a': 'ah',
    'e': 'eh',
    'i': 'ee',
    'o': 'oh',
    'u': 'oo'
}

vowelPairs = {
    'ai': 'eye',
    'ae': 'eye',
    'ao': 'ow',
    'au': 'ow',
    'ei': 'ay',
    'eu': 'eh-oo',
    'iu': 'ew',
    'oi': 'oyo',
    'ou': 'ow',
    'ui': 'ooey',
    'iw': 'v',
    'ew': 'v'
}
# Not used but is part of it so is in dictionary for reference
constants = {
    'p': 'p',
    'k': 'k',
    'h': 'h',
    'l': 'l',
    'm': 'm',
    'n': 'n'
}

# Checks for valid characters in the input
def check(word):
    valid = ['p', 'k', 'h', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'w',
             'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', ' ', '\'']
    for c in word:
        c = c.lower()
        if valid.count(c) == 0:
            print(c, ' is not a valid character.')
            return False
    return True

def soundout(part):
    lower_part = part.lower()
    result = ''
    part_len = len(lower_part)
    
    if part_len < 2:
        result = vowels.get(lower_part)
    else:
        for i, char in enumerate(lower_part):
            if constants.get(char):
                if (i-1) < 0:
                    result += char
                elif vowels.get(lower_part[i-1]):
                    result += "-" + char
            else:
                if i < part_len-1:
                    pair = char + lower_part[i+1]
                    if vowelPairs.get(pair):
                        result += vowelPairs.get(pair)
                    elif vowels.get(char):
                        result += vowels.get(char)
                elif vowels.get(char):
                    if ((i-1) > -1) and vowels.get(lower_part[i-1]):
                        pass
                    else:
                        result += vowels.get(char)
                
    return result

def pronounce(word):
    wordResult = []
    parts = word.split(' ')
    for part in parts:
        wordResult.append(soundout(part))
    
    return(' '.join(wordResult).capitalize())



# Eh koh-moh meye
check('E komo mai')
pronounce('E komo mai')
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
'Eh koh-moh meye'
```